# Getting 'ModuleNotFoundError' while using prompt

Tags: python

I'm trying to run a program using anaconda prompt, when i enter

```
python program.py
```

everything works correctly. But when i enter

```
python3 program.py
```

i get the following error:

```
    import numpy as np
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

I have Python 3.8.6 and 3.9 versions on my computer.
I have already installed all the necessary libraries.
How can i use any installed library with using `python3` too? Thank you.

Comment: What OS are you on? If you are on MacOS or Linux, what is the output of `which python` and `which python3`.

Comment: I'm using Windows 10.

Comment: Have you installed libraries using both `pip install` AND `pip3 install`? It's possible that your `python3` has a different PATH then `python`, therefore any pip installs have to be performed on both separately

Comment: When i enter `pip3 install numpy`, prompt shows `Requirement already satisfied`

Comment: Maybe you have to use ```pip3 install``` from inside the anaconda prompt, or use ```conda install```

Comment: I'm already typing installation codes into the anaconda prompt, i tried `conda install`, it installed numpy again but i'm still getting the error.

Comment: Did you activate the conda environment? Maybe you are running Python outside the place where the libraries are installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. check python version by python3 -V or get path by which python3

```
$python3 -V
Python 3.6.9
```

2. go to that path ->lib-> site-packages-> check for numpy folder if it's not there then you will need to install it.

```
$python3.6 -m pip install numpy
```